# DATALENGTH is not counting no-breakspace (0xA0) characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

`DATALENGTH` is not counting no-breakspace (`0xA0`) characters while returning the number of Bytes in a string in SQL Server. In PostgreSQL, `OCTET_LENGTH` which count the number of bytes in a specified string includes `0xA0` as well while returning result set. Is this a bug in SQL Server?

Example -

Both of these below return 9 as output:

```
SELECT DATALENGTH('Blah Blah'); --contains no-breakspace
```

You can look up the no-break space character on the above select via => https://unicodelookup.com/

```
SELECT DATALENGTH('Blah Blah');
```

Is there any other function available in SQL server that would count this in as well ? `LEN` did not help.

Comment: Seems to be counting it for me: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5db47243f3f11396593b2bbf593c7264). If it didn't, the second value would be `8` not `9`.

Comment: Also, the code you have pasted does **not** have a no-breakspace character in it. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0f8488a3195abe2d3703692b7f44e151)

Comment: [duplicate](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/943ab295-c103-46f8-bd70-d9e81b268200/datalength-is-not-counting-nobreakspace-0xa0-characters-in-sql-server?forum=transactsql) on msdn

Comment: Probably posted the same question on msdn since there is not downvote feature there.

Comment: @DanGuzman Appreciate your answer Dan! I was a genuine question I had! Now I understand which direction I should taken when approaching problems like this. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is UTF-8 encoded in PostgreSQL. The resultant number of bytes is 10 because 8 bytes are needed for the 8 ASCII characters (0-127 code point range) plus 2 bytes for the no-breakspace character.

Only 9 bytes are needed with the SQL Server varchar data type because non-ASCII characters are mapped according to the collation code page. Only 1 byte is needed to store the no-breakspace character without Unicode encoding, for a total of 9 bytes for the same value.